# node.js: using foreach with a multidimensional array

Tags: node.js, multidimensional-array, foreach

im trying to call a function with every line of an array which is an array itself. So far I always get an error with my code, which I cant seem to straighten out. Can someone tell me how to do it right?
The output should be "['a', 4], ['b', 1], ['j', 2], ['c', 3], ['d', 5], ['e', 2], ['f', 2], ['g', 6]".

```
var testqueue = [['a', 4], ['b', 1], ['j', 2], ['c', 3], ['d', 5], ['e', 2], ['f', 2], ['g', 6]];

function test(cb){

testqueue.foreach(function(item){
console.log(item);
});
cb('done');
}

test(function(result){
console.log(result);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it was only a typo :(

it should be forEach (capital E) and everything works fine.